# Javascript Injection with Xamarin forms WebView

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.forms, javascript-injection

**I want to change the value of an element inside a Xamarin forms `WebView`**

I created a new project and added a `WebView` page that loads https://www.google.com/
I have used .Eval

`m_GoogleWebView.Eval("alert('coolness!');");`

This alerts fine for me. However if I try to access the dom at all, it just replaces the WebView with the text 'test text'

```
m_GoogleWebView.Eval("document.getElementById('lst-ib').value='test text';");
```

How should I manipulate elements from Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue with any WebView on Android after 4.1.

What you need to do, is assign your script to a variable like this

```
m_GoogleWebView.Eval("var x = document.getElementById('lst-ib').value='test text';");
```

This still runs the script but now just assigns the result to the variable instead of the DOM.